# How to remember NFA's choice on a certain computation?

Tags: regular-language, automata, formal-languages, non-deterministic

I'm working on solving the question answered at this page but with different values at the table, my alphabet is {a,b,c}
[Words that have the same right- and left-associative product](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1467/words-that-have-the-same-right-and-left-associative-product)

Currently I'm in the stage where I have drawn the DFA of the multiplication table, found its reverse which was an NFA.

Here is the NFA I got by reversing the multiplication table's DFA

[image]

I apology for the miss draw, but I hope its readable.

Now I have taken the input "abcb" and applied it on the above NFA, and I have gone through this tree

Tree

[image]

As you can see here that the input is all consumed at the branch "C" and I could reach the Final State. Would someone elaborate to me how can I backtrack from that branch which is "C" in this case and indicate that the "C" is the state which shall be marked as the Final State my NFA?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CS Stack Exchange.